# The URI string is too Long exception - Making a request to node.js

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, uri

I just ran into this issue while making a GET request to a node.js server from .NET.  Ultimately, I am trying to pass a large JSON object through the query string. I have been looking to see if there is a way to increase the size of the URI in .NET itself.  I know that node has no restrictions on the size of the query string that it can accept. Is there a way to increase this size or are we better off changing this to a POST?

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: `POST` is *always* the best approach for sending large volumes of data.

Comment: You are better off using a post. Servers will usually max out at around 2000 characters whereas browsers are different for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change it, because underlying all of Microsoft http technology is INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH, which is defined to be 2083 characters.

You should just use POST for everything.  Odds are it isn't very difficult to make the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST. IIS maxes out ~2000 characters for a GET request and even if it didn't [each browser has a different maximum length](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) with IE being the most restrictive. In general keep GETs less than 2000 characters for maximum compatibility with all possible web clients otherwise switch to a POST.